# Why is my Perl code not omitting newlines?

Tags: perl

I'm reading this textfile to get ONLY the words in it and ignore all kind of whitespaces:

```
hello
now
    do you see this.sadslkd.das,msdlsa but 
      i   hoohoh
```

And this is my Perl code:

```
#!usr/bin/perl -w
require 5.004;

open F1, './text.txt';

while ($line = <F1>) {

    #print $line;
    @arr = split /\s+/, $line;
    foreach $w (@arr) {

        if ($w !~ /^\s+$/) {

            print $w."\n";
        }
    }
    #print @arr;
}
close F1;
```

And this is the output:

```
hello
now

do
you
see
this.sadslkd.das,msdlsa
but

i
hoohoh
```

The output is showing two newlines but I am expecting the output to be just words. What should I do to just get words?

Comment: I see you've not declared any of your variables in the sample code.  Take a look at this: http://perl.about.com/b/2006/09/21/why-you-should-use-strict.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
@arr=split(/\s+/,$line);
```

`\s+` does a match just before the leading spaces. Use `' '` instead.

```
@arr=split(' ',$line);
```

Comment: So basically when you use the first parameter as a constant string in the split function, it doesn't care if the leading portion of the string $line contains the first parameter or not, but if you use a regexp that changes?

Comment: Yes. Using a literal single-space string as the separator parameter is a special case that makes `split` find all sequences of non-space characters in the string

Answer (score 3):

You should *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` (in preference to the `-w` command-line qualifier) at the top of every Perl program, and declare each variable at its first point of use using `my`. That way Perl will tell you about simple errors that you may otherwise overlook.

You should also use lexical file handles with the three-parameter form of `open`, and check the status to make sure it succeeded. There is little point in explicitly closing an input file unless you expect your program to run for an appreciable time, as Perl will close all files for you on exit.

Do you really need to `require` Perl v5.4? That version is fifteen years old, and if there is anything older than that installed then you have a museum!

Your program would be better like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', './text.txt' or die $!;

while (my $line = <$fh>) {

    my @arr = split /\s+/, $line;

    foreach my $w (@arr) {
        if ($w !~ /^\s+$/) {
            print $w."\n";
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: my apologies. The `warnings` pragma and lexical file handles were introduced only in v5.6 so that part of my answer is irrelevant. The latest version of Perl is v5.16 and you really should upgrade

As [Birei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/773159/birei) has pointed out, the problem is that, when the line has leading whitespace, there is a empty field *before* the first separator. Imagine if your data was comma-separated, then you would want Perl to report a leading empty field if the line started with a comma.

To extract all the non-space characters you can use a regular expression that does exactly that

```
my @arr = $line =~ /\S+/g;
```

and this can be emulated by using the *default* parameter for `split` which is a single *quoted* space (*not* a regular expression)

```
my @arr = $line =~ split ' ', $line;
```

In this case `split` behaves like the `awk` utility and discards any leading empty fields as you expected.

This is even simpler if you let Perl use the `$_` variable in the read loop, as all of the parameters for `split` can be defaulted:

```
while (<F1>) {
    my @arr = split;
    foreach my $w (@arr) {
        print "$w\n" if $w !~ /^\s+$/;
    }
}
```

Comment: /\s+/g doesn't work saying "Use of /g modifier is meaningless in split at term_freq.pl line 12." And this is actually true right?
Also the above is my first perl program, so I'm having a lot of difficulty understanding your shorthand code.

Comment: If you read my answer I don't use `/\S+/g` with `split`. The regex simply looks for all sequences of non-space characters and puts them into `@arr`. Note that it has an upper-case `S` - `\S` matches any non-space character. Perl is unusual in its use of the default variable `$_`, but it simplifies code a lot. `while (<F1>) {...}` reads a line from the file into `$_` and `split` on its own is the same as `split ' ', $_`. You should get used to using `$_` if you expect to write much Perl

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in this line:

```
if(!($w =~ /^\s+$/))
```

You wanted to ask if there's nothing in this row - don't print it.
But the "+" in the REGEX actually force it to have at least 1 space.

If you change the "\s+" to "\s*", you'll see that it's working. because * is 0 occurrences or more ...

Comment: No. * would match basically every character since it is followed and preceeded by zero occurances of a space. It doesn't work. I checked it too.